# The correct condition to print only those words that have all char as the array of string

Tags: c, string, file

We have a dictionary file that contains words. We need to read this file and print words that are only made up of characters that exist in a particular set { `'m'`, `'o'`, `'n'`, `'k'`, `'e'`, `'y'` }. (These have words have a fixed length. So if length = 2, then word can be 'no', 'on', etc.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[200000];
    int len;
    fp = fopen("E:\\University\\SEMESTER 1\\C Programs + Assignments + Practice Programs\\Dictionary.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",ch) != EOF){
        len = strlen(ch);
        if(len==2){
            if(*ch == 'm' || *ch == 'n' || *ch == 'o' || *ch == 'k' || *ch == 'e' || *ch == 'y'){
                printf("\n%s",ch);
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(fp,"\n%s",ch);
    fp = fopen("E:\\University\\SEMESTER 1\\C Programs + Assignments + Practice Programs\\DictionaryOP.txt","w");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is this part of the code:

```
if(len==2){
    if(*ch == 'm' || *ch == 'n' || *ch == 'o' || *ch == 'k' || *ch == 'e' || *ch == 'y'){
        printf("\n%s",ch);
    }
}
```

I get output where the second character is not present in the specified array. How can I avoid this?

Comment: i can use like,  putting all condition for each words of length 2 separately,  but it wont work for lengths like 4,5,6  T_T

Comment: So you need a loop or so.

Comment: i tried  for loop with *ch[i]  but it kept showing unary error

Comment: What is the type of `ch` and of `*ch[i]`? Please think about that and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the first string and test that each character (not just the first as `*ch` is doing) exists in the character set (`"monkey"`). [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) is a helpful function for this.

Here is an example program that does this in a length-ignorant way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int all_characters_in(const char *target, const char *source) {
    while (*target)
        if (!strchr(source, *target++))
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    char *list[] = {
        "moon", "key", "monk", "mono", "meow", "make", "keen"
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof list / sizeof *list); i++)
        printf("%s all in %s ? %s\n",
                list[i], "monkey", all_characters_in(list[i], "monkey") ?
                    "yes" : "no");
}
```

If strings need to be only a certain length then test for length beforehand, but it is not relevant to the character set itself.

Also note that `void main()` is strictly wrong. `main` has two valid signatures: `int main(int, char **)` and `int main(void)`.

Comment: `target[strspn(target, source)] == 0` is a neater way to express `all_characters_in`.

Comment: @PaulHankin Clever! I think clearly demonstrating the loop here is still helpful, though.

Comment: finally after using your code and modifying it according to the dictionary content it worked , thankyou

Comment: @PranayKatyal Make sure to [accept the answer if it solved your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).